# How can this batch file end its own process?

Tags: batch-file

So I have this batch file that starts a power shell script that never ends. It works great minus the fact that the batch file process on task manager stays running and wont close after the power shell script process starts running. Could anyone help me fix this code to close after it runs.

Here is the bat file code

```
@echo on
Powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden -file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reboot Scheduler\Reboot.ps1"
exit
```

Comment: If you want the batch file process to end then use the `START` command to launch the `POWERSHELL` process.

Comment: @Squashman I had the same idea. Perhaps post this as an answer with `/min` switch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand why it won't quit, but I wonder if you simply used a 'call' to powershell if that might help (because it would ensure that the control was returned to the batch)

e.g.,

```
@echo on
call Powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden -file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reboot Scheduler\Reboot.ps1"
exit
```

Comment: @Raplh `Call` is supposed to be used for "Calling" other `.bat` file(s) not programs, I think.